# combine 2 read /write methods into one

Tags: java

I have written 2 methods - A write to method and a read from method. They work fine but I want to combine them so that they work like the pseudo code that I have written:

```
prompt user for input filename
open input file
prompt user for output filename
open output file
while there are lines in the input file
    read a line
    print it to screen
    writeit to the output file
close the input file
close the output file
```

I have tried a few different variations  but I can't seem to get this to work?

Read to method:

```
 public void readFile()
{
    FileReader fileReader = null;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    String InputFileName;

    String nextLine;

    clrscr();
    System.out.println("Please enter the name of the file that is to be READ (e.g. aFile.txt: ");
    InputFileName = Genio.getString();

    try
    {

        fileReader = new FileReader(InputFileName);

        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader); 

        nextLine = bufferedReader.readLine();


        while (nextLine != null)
        {

            System.out.println(nextLine);

            nextLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Sorry, there has been a problem opening or reading from the file");
    }
    finally
    {

        if (bufferedReader != null)
        {

            try
            {
                bufferedReader.close();    
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println("An error occurred when attempting to close the file");
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

Write to method:

```
public void writeFile()
{
    String myString;
    clrscr();
    System.out.println("Begin typing the contents to you wish to WRITE to file: ");
    myString = Genio.getString();
    System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
    FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
    PrintWriter printWriter = null;

    try
    {
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream("writing.txt");

        printWriter = new PrintWriter(outputStream); 
        printWriter.write(myString);
        printWriter.println("\n");
        // write information to the file via the PrintWriter
        while (!myString.equals(""))
        {
            myString = Genio.getString();
            printWriter.print(myString + "\n");
        }

        System.out.println("File: 'writing.txt' has been saved with the contents above.\n\nYou can now open this file using the other options in the menu screen.");
        pressKey();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Sorry, there has been a problem opening or writing to the file");
    }
    finally
    {

        if (printWriter != null)
        {

            printWriter.close();    
        }
    }
}
```

The Genio class that deals with user input:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Genio
{

public Genio()
{
}

private static String getStr() 
{
    String inputLine = "";
    BufferedReader reader = 
        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    try 
    {
        inputLine = reader.readLine();
    }

    catch(Exception exc) 
    {
        System.out.println ("There was an error during reading: "
                            + exc.getMessage());
    }
    return inputLine;
}

public static int getInteger()
{
    int temp=0;
    boolean OK = false;

    BufferedReader keyboard = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    do 
    {
        try
        {
            temp = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.readLine());
            OK = true;
        }

        catch (Exception eRef)
        {
            if (eRef instanceof NumberFormatException) 
            {
                System.out.print("Integer value needed: ");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Please report this error: "+eRef.toString());
            }
        }

    } while(OK == false);
    return(temp);
 }

public static float getFloat()
{
    float temp=0;
    boolean OK = false;

    BufferedReader keyboard = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    do 
    {
        try
        {
            temp = Float.parseFloat(keyboard.readLine());
            OK = true;
        }


        catch (Exception eRef)
        {
            if (eRef instanceof NumberFormatException) 
            {
                System.out.print("Number needed: ");
            } 
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Please report this error: "+eRef.toString());
            }
        }

    } while(OK == false);

    return(temp);
 }

public static double getDouble()
{
    double temp=0;
    boolean OK = false;
    BufferedReader keyboard = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    do 
    {
        try
        {
            temp = Double.parseDouble(keyboard.readLine());
            OK = true;
        }

        catch (Exception eRef)
        {
            if (eRef instanceof NumberFormatException) 
            {
                System.out.print("Number needed: ");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Please report this error: "+eRef.toString());
            }
        }

    } while(OK == false);

    return(temp);
 }

 public static char getCharacter()
 {
     String tempStr="";
     char temp=' ';
     boolean OK = false;
     do 
     {
         try
         {
             tempStr = getStr();
             temp = tempStr.charAt(0);
             OK = true;
         }

         catch (Exception eRef)
         {
             if (eRef instanceof StringIndexOutOfBoundsException)
             {
                 // means nothing was entered so prompt ...
                 System.out.print("Enter a character: ");
             }            
             else 
             {
                 System.out.println("Please report this error: "+eRef.toString());
             }
         }

     } while(OK == false);

     return(temp);
 }


 public static String getString()
 {
    String temp="";
    try
    {
        temp = getStr();
    }
    catch (Exception eRef)
    {
        System.out.println("Please report this error: "+eRef.toString());
    }
    return(temp);
 }     
}
```

Comment: What is not working exactly ?

Comment: Maybe PipedOutputStream/PipedInputStream could help? (http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/pipes.html)

Comment: @jeroen_de_schutter Just a I said. I have the pseudo code that I feel is correct, but when I try to program it, I can't it working correctly?